# javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException: error 10061 in socket::open

Tags: sockets, java-me, packet

`javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException: error 10061 in socket::open`

I have this error with j2me - in execution.

I tried searching, but it didn't help.

Code:

```
Connector.open("socket://127.0.0.1:7777")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [`ConnectionNotFoundException`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/ConnectionNotFoundException.html) documentation "This class is used to signal that a connection target cannot be found, or the protocol type is not supported".

`socket` is a supported protocol, so the connection target cannot be found. Be sure that 127.0.0.1:7777 is up, running and that is does support receiving a Socket connection.

You may try below Java code:

```
public class Server {
    static boolean done = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(7777);

            while (!done) {
                final Socket socket = server.accept();
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        treatSocket(socket);
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void treatSocket(Socket socket) {
        // treat socket data
    }
}
```